# using python recursion to calculate the Parenthesis part not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, calculator, calc

If I enter input with parentheses it resolves only what is inside the parentheses and not what is after or before, if I enter two expressions with parentheses it returns None.
you can see it in the code.

```
def divide(a, b):
    return a/b
def pow(a, b):
    return a**b
def addA(a, b):
    return a+b
def subA(a, b):
    return a-b
def mul (a, b):
    return a*b
operators = {
  '+': addA,
  '-': subA,
  '*': mul,
  '/': divide,
  '^' : pow,


}

def calculate(s):
    if s.isdigit():
        return float(s)
    elif '[' in s:
        start = s.index('[')
        end = s.rindex(']')
        return calculate(s[start + 1:end])
    for c in operators.keys():
        left, operator, right = s.partition(c)
        if operator in operators:
            return operators[operator](calculate(left), calculate(right))

calc = input("Type calculation:\n")
print("Answer: " + str(calculate(calc)))
```

input: [2+2]+[2+2]
output: None

input [2+3]*2
output 5

Answer (score 0):

Nice idea.

```
    elif '[' in s:
        ...
        return calculate(s[start + 1:end])
```

Beautifully simple.
But, alas, wrong.

Consider `1+1+1+[8+9]+2+2+2`.

Is there a `[` bracket in there? Yes.
And the recursive call correctly computes 17.
But we're ignoring the 1's and the 2's.

Also, when the `for` finishes and we fall of the
end of the function we `return None`.
Consider doing something else in that case,
perhaps `raise` a fatal error.

---

You probably want to invert the order of `operations`,
so higher priority ops will bind more tightly.

---

You will find you can iterate through the edit - debug
cycle much more quickly if you write some simple
[unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
that lock in "working" behavior. Only the last test fails ATM.

```
class CalculateTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_addition(self):
        self.assertEqual(5, calculate("2+3"))
        self.assertEqual(5, calculate("[2+3]"))
        self.assertEqual(9, calculate("2+3+4"))
        self.assertEqual(9, calculate("2+[3+4]"))
```

I found it convenient to have the function always return a `float`.

---

Once you have this function in better shape, please
[let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
how it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

The calculate function took into account the first and last parenthesis, skipping the middle ones.

Try the following:

```
def extract_expression(s):
    start = s.rindex('[')
    end = s.rindex(']')
    return s[start + 1:end]


def calculate(expr):
    for c in operators.keys():
        left, operator, right = expr.partition(c)
        if operator in operators:
            return operators[operator](float(left), float(right))


def solution(s):
    while '[' in s:
        sub_expression = extract_expression(s)
        result = calculate(sub_expression)
        s = s.replace('[' + sub_expression + ']', str(result))

    if s.isdigit():
        return float(s)

    return calculate(s)


calc = input("Type calculation:\n")
print("Answer: " + str(solution(calc)))
```

input: [2+2]+[2+2],
output: 8.0

input: [2+3]*2,
output: 10.0

input: 2+[2+2],
output: 6.0

Comment: hi, i tried your code with this input 2+[2+2] and it give me this error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\idona\PycharmProjects\test\קס2.py", line 41, in <module>
    print("Answer: " + str(calculate(calc)))
  File "C:\Users\idona\PycharmProjects\test\קס2.py", line 38, in calculate
    return operators[operator](calculate(left), calculate(right))
  File "C:\Users\idona\PycharmProjects\test\קס2.py", line 6, in addA
    return a+b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Comment: @bob999 I made an update that should work.

Comment: _input: 2+[2+3], output: 6.0_ <-- this doesn't look good ;)

Comment: @Ack, I updated the answer. It was a typo.